# Sysinternals ProcDump -e usage

Tags: sysinternals, procdump

I am rather new to using the procdump.exe utility and I am trying to find out why a process I am running is crashing without generating a crash dump or writing out an unhandled exception to the log. I am using the following command line

procdump.exe -e -t *pid* C:\DumpFiles\Process.dmp

As I am running this against the process that is having issues, I don't see any dump file being generated though I am seeing the following exception many times:

Exception: E0434352.CLR

According to one website I looked at, that particular exception get generated whenever there is an unhandled exception, which isn't particularly helpful to me. Also, I am not sure how true that information I got was. I was wondering if there was a way to get procdump to spit out a dump file when it encounters an exception like that so I can see what is going on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

E0434352.CLR is an error code that represents .NET exceptions and it is used by the CLR, therefore I assume that your process is managed code. Adding the ['-g' switch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) (Run as a native debugger in a managed process) will provide you the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As @yonisha said, "E0434352.CLR" is a general message for all .NET Exceptions.

But, you can check specific .NET Exception if you add "1" value to "-e" option as follows,

`procdump -e 1 -f "" [Your Process ID]`

After applying that option, procdump will print E0434352.CLR as .NET Exception like this.

`[14:54:53] Exception: E0434F4D.System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ("Could not find a part of the path 'c:\myfile\test.dat'.")`

Once you could identified what kind of .NET Exception, you can dump it with these options.

`procdump -ma -e 1 -f "DirectoryNotFoundException" [Your Process ID] c:\temp\test.dmp`

Comment: even after using -e 1 -f "", I'm still not able to see the elaborated detail of the exception as you shown above